# Running Gunicorn as non root user

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I am running python app with Gunicorn http server. As part of security hardening, we are moving from root user to dedicated user running the process.

Are there any files (except PID / config / app files) used by Gunicorn? I'm scared of the thought that we encounter in near future a permission problem for accessing files

Answer (score 1):

If you're really worried, you can startup `gunicorn` with strace and see what it opens. Running as a non-root user is a pretty standard configuration, and gunicorn is conceptually pretty simple, so  if it starts and runs for a minute you're probably good.

Some things you do need to worry about with gunicorn is the heartbeat system blocking everything, and not enough threads causing load balancer queries to not get responses. See here for some suggestions on fixing this: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/

Comment: I'm scared of the possibility that I would get every 100 request one big request that will be buffered to the disk. Starting gunicorn won't raise the problem I'm afraid of

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn is creating temp files in project folder:

```
  File "/home/**/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/pidfile.py", line 36, in create
    fd, fname = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=fdir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 344, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 262, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/src/tmpqg7t98e3'
```

hence own the project root folder to make it work